# Super + D broken

Tags: shortcut-keys

Ubuntu 11.10. The Super + D stopped minimizing all windows. The combination does nothing.
It worked a couple of days ago as I was using it a lot.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Bob.

Comment: Are you using Unity2D?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ctrl+Alt+D`

if didn't work --> open system settings --> keyboard --> Shortcuts tap --> Navigation --> `Hide all normal windows` --> set it to super+D
[image: keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: That's the one that works for me, not super-D, which does nothing.

Comment: I think it is the default for Ubuntu 11.10 i don't know how `super+D` work with Bob until now, but you can change it if you want as i mention above

Comment: I thought about that too (the fact that it reputedly worked before), but as a person that helps users with problems fairly often, I know how users often misremember things like that. :-)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Super + D will work in the upcoming 12.04..... Sorry about that.<g>